# CListBox item background

Tags: mfc, clistbox

I need to set background CListBox background.
I can't find solution for set different colors for each item.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To get different colors for each item you have to owner-draw the list box. That means you must paint each item yourself. See the CTRLTEST sample in MSDN.